# How to copy all data from source sheet to destination sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made a Google Sheet that serves to keep track of lot numbers within a manufacturing setting. Right now, when the onEdit trigger is enabled, the data from the source sheet only doubles first row of data in the destination sheet. Here's the link to the [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11WqCgr7PcG-HWQhdjsl49tBVHkoXMH5WC0ITfMpI8hg/edit?usp=sharing). This is the code I have so far:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
      if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'N2') {
        if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
          eval(e.value)();
          e.range.clear();
        }
      }
    }
    function Reset() {
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if( s.getName() == "Input" ) {
      var dataRange = s.getRange('A5:V14');
    var values = dataRange.clearContent();
    s.getRange("C5:C14").setValue('-');
    s.getRange("F5:F14").setValue('-');
    s.getRange("I5:I14").setValue('-');
    s.getRange("L5:L14").setValue('-');
      }
    }
    function Submit() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Input');
      const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
      const data = sh.getRange(5,1,1,23).getValues(); // A5:W14
      targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you added the right code? The onEdit function do not do what it was described.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is?
[And](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

Comment: The problem you have with the code only adding the first row twice is coming from the following  line in `Submit()` function: `const data = sh.getRange(5,1,1,23).getValues(); // A5:W14` The method [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) you are telling it to only get one row.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm still learning the lingo in Apps Script. What I meant to ask was how can I use the Submit() function to send the information from the 'Input' sheet to the 'Database' sheet without sending the blank rows with the hyphens. Right now, the function only sends the first row twice, as opposed to all the data typed in the 'Input' sheet. The 'Database' sheet will serve as production records for the company. If possible, I'd also like to send the date from cell B1 on the 'Input' sheet to the 'Database' sheet along each row that has data submitted that particular day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are worried that when you select Submit, there is a double insert of data into the Database sheet.
It can be assumed that this is due to the Submit function being run twice. The first time when checking /^\w+$/.test(e.value) and the second time directly when you run eval(e.value)().
I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature :-)

Try this code, it works:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'N2') {
    var val = e.value;
    switch(val) {
      case 'Reset': Reset();
        break;
      case 'Submit': Submit();
        break;
    }
    e.range.clear();
  }
}
```

**Upd.**

The double insertion is due to the fact that you are using 2 onEdit() triggers. Have a look at Edith / Triggers of the current project. Delete it.
[image]

**Upd2.**

If you want only filled rows out of 10 to appear on the Database sheet then use this code. It filters the rows based on whether there is some text in column H, such as Adult or Pediatric.

```
function Submit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Input');
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  var data = sh.getRange(5,1,10,23).getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  var fData = data.filter(data => (data[13] != ""));
  Logger.log(fData);
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,3,fData.length,fData[0].length).setValues(fData);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! However, I'm am getting the following error  when attempting to save it "Syntax error. line: 30 file: Code" for this line of code: ```var fData = data.filter(data => (data[13] != ""));```

Comment: Turn on Apps Script V8 in the Run menu.